# How to get all days in month?

Tags: sql, oracle

Possible to get all days in month in Oracle SQL/PLSQL as table ?

select * from bla-bla-bla  DUAL

results:

```
1 rec: 01.01.2012
2 rec: 02.01.2012
3 rec: 03.01.2012
...
4 rec: 31.01.2012
```

?

Comment: this might help https://community.oracle.com/thread/340389?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 7):

this is what you are looking for;

```
select to_date('01.01.2012','dd.mm.yyyy')+level-1
 from dual 
 connect by level <= TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(to_date('01.01.2012','dd.mm.yyyy')),'DD')
```

Comment: What about months that have more than 30 days, or February (which has 28 except in leap years)?

Comment: `LAST_DAY` returns always the last day of given month, considering number of days and leap years.

Answer (score 2):

`ADD_MONTHS (dt, 1) - dt` is also an alternative.

For a particular month of an year, you need to hardcode the date :

```
WITH d AS
  (SELECT TRUNC ( to_date('01.01.2012','dd.mm.yyyy'), 'MM' ) - 1 AS dt
  FROM dual
  )
SELECT dt + LEVEL 
   FROM d 
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ADD_MONTHS (dt, 1) - dt
/
```

Else, to get the list for current month, simply use SYSDATE instead of hardcoding the date :

```
SQL> WITH d AS
  2    (SELECT TRUNC(sysdate,'MM') -1 AS dt FROM dual
  3    )
  4  SELECT dt + LEVEL
  5     FROM d
  6    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ADD_MONTHS (dt, 1) - dt
  7  /

DT+LEVEL
---------
01-OCT-14
02-OCT-14
03-OCT-14
04-OCT-14
05-OCT-14
06-OCT-14
07-OCT-14
08-OCT-14
09-OCT-14
10-OCT-14
11-OCT-14
12-OCT-14
13-OCT-14
14-OCT-14
15-OCT-14
16-OCT-14
17-OCT-14
18-OCT-14
19-OCT-14
20-OCT-14
21-OCT-14
22-OCT-14
23-OCT-14
24-OCT-14
25-OCT-14
26-OCT-14
27-OCT-14
28-OCT-14
29-OCT-14
30-OCT-14
31-OCT-14

31 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: That was useful to my case, thank.